# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0/JQuery 1.9.1 Modal Rendering Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've gone through a bunch of the articles on this and tried many things and just can't figure out what is going wrong.  Basically I've added a very simple modal to my page and when I invoke 'show' it fades the background and brings up a very messed up looking version of the modal, and only when I remove 'hide'.

**Please** look at the JSFiddle code before answering, any links you post I can all but guarantee I've already visited.  Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/tY3Nj/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="assignModal" class="fade modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4>Add Assignment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Use me to add an assignment!
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using version 2 markup with version 3 CSS and JavaScript.

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals for the proper v3 markup.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="assignModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Assignment</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Use me to add an assignment!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Updated demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/tY3Nj/1/

When upgrading major versions, you should always take care to read any notes and especially [migration guides](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration). From [Migrating from 2.x to 3.0 - Additional notes](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration-notes)...

> Modal markup has changed significantly. The `.modal-header`, `.modal-body`, and `.modal-footer` sections now get wrapped in `.modal-content` and `.modal-dialog` for improved mobile styling and behavior.

Comment: Interesting, I grabbed the sample from their site today but I guess somehow I got to the v2 html - Ill check it out later thanks!

Comment: @ShaneKenyon A lot of the old links (such as twitter.github.com/bootstrap) redirect to http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/. Just keep an eye on the URL :)